# How to decorate interface driven controllers in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have a interface driven controller like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')")
@RequestMapping("/foo")
interface Foo {
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    String bar(String id);
}
```

And an implementation delegating to the actual business logic

```
@Controller
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    @Override
    public String bar(String id) {
        return "<actual business logic>";
    }
}
```

I would like to decorate interface `Foo` to add additional functionality to the application.

However when I use a jdk proxy and try to start the application with that spring won't register the endpoints anymore. This is because the bean now isn't annotated with `@Controller` anymore on the beans type. The annotation is only present on the implementation (and I can't use a `@Bean` method because that annotation is only allowed on types) and not the proxy, which is now the type spring web mvc sees. I also can't annotate the decoration and implementation with @Controller because then I will have ambigous mappings since the decoration interface and the implementation will be treated as components where handler mappings need to be created for.

I would also like to keep the controller annotation at the implementation for the actual business logic so that its still obvious where the main focus of the controller is.

So how can I decorate an interface driven controller in spring web mvc keeping the actual implementation and any decorations that shall be applied to it distinct?

Comment: Enable class proxies instead of interface proxies or just ditch the interface, what is the usage anyway? It alwaus feels weird (wrong?) to use interfaces for controllers. The use of classbased proxies is also stated in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying) for Spring MVC.

Comment: @M.Deinum The actual use case is an attribute based access control scheme for a rest api. One implementation of the controller interface cares about the actual business logic. A second only cares about deciding whether to grant access. By being interface driven accidental access control bypasses are prevented because a developer also  needs to implement the method in the access control controller implementation.

Comment: Using an interface doesn't help with that, there is nothing preventing a developer to **not** implement the said interface and just use annotations. Anyway as mentioned you need to enable class based proxies with controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an additional interface for adding back the `@Controller` annotation to the created proxy:

```
@Controller
public interface AddControllerAnnotations {
}
```

And I'm passing this interface additionally to the interfaces of the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(ClassLoader, Class<?>[], InvocationHandler)` call I'm using to create the proxy instance. This way spring will still consider the decorated instance as a controller.

However this will not scale if there will be more annotations to apply this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using proxies with Spring Controllers requires class based proxies, there is even [a section in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying) explaining this, with an additional note on the changes in Spring Framework 6.

To force class proxies enable those in all the annotations you have to use proxies, like `@EnableTransactionManagement`, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` etc.